# Nitration of Naphthalene Having Electron Withdrawing Group

Tags: organic-chemistry

In the following nitration which one out of 50 and 51 will be the major product.

[image]

In my book it is said that (51) will be major.But in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22-Sou-4Q5o) it is said that (50) will be major.I'm confused.

Oh yes I saw this answer too [Nitration in anthracene and naphthalene](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10736/nitration-in-anthracene-and-naphthalene) but did'nt help in my case.

Comment: If you look at p.450 onwards in Chemical Micro Process Engineering: Fundamentals, Modelling and Reactions by  Volker Hessel, Steffen Hardt and Holger Löwe, the major nitration product can be controlled to be mono. Conversely,  if you put this sort of system under forcing conditions,  you could favour a trinitro product. This is why these sort of set questions belong in the 19th century

Comment: @Beerhunter PLEASE read my question once again...

Comment: I think you cannot predict the outcome of 50:51 selectivity by theory and you need to look up the original paper (or try it yourself). However I wouldn't be surprised if 2 different labs report contradicting results since this kind of nitration reaction is not easy to control (violent and exothermic), and slight variations of the experimental conditions (scale, stirring, temperature control etc) can possibly lead to different results.

Comment: @K_P Ok ignoring this particular reaction.What if just mono nitro napthalene is nitrated using nitrating mixture? Even that can't be predicted?

Comment: Draw resonance structures of 48. Where are the positive charges?

Comment: @SanchayanDutta  I would expect as in your original question wrt to 50:51 selectivity that sterics would favour 50 but this would be on the assumption that there is no difference in electronics. But if your book is correct then this assumption is not right so maybe a more subtle / complex theoretic approach (computational chemistry? ) is required compared to the simpler explanation that works for 48:49 selectivity.

Comment: The reaction conditions are not plausible!  Dinitrogen trioxide $\ce{ON-NO2}$ has a "boiling" point around -3 °C, where it signficantly decomposes: $\ce{N2O3 <=> NO + NO2}$. I suspect that the reagent is in fact $\ce{N2O5}$.